# git-flow change default workflow

Tags: git, git-flow

Does anyone know if it is possible to change git flow to use more than 3 branches?

Currently we use the std workflow:

```
dev -> feature/*  ->  dev
dev -> release/* -> master
master -> hotfix/* -> master & dev
```

However our setup has now substantially expanded and are looking for the following workflow

```
dev -> feature/* -> dev
dev -> stage/* -> staging
staging -> bug/* -> staging
staging -> release/* -> master & dev
master -> hotfix/* -> master & staging & dev
```

The altered workflow will enable devs to continue building and sharing new features, even during the testing of a staged release. Also enabling other devs to bug fix any issues on the upcoming release.

Comment: The git flow tools are just a combination of scripts that automate the git branching processes. You *can* extend them and/or add your own relatively easily. You'll probably end up copy and pasting the "bugfix" or "feature" command for example, and tweaking the destination branch to be "staging" etc. In terms of that workflow however I imagine you might end up with some hefty overheads in terms of managing merge conflicts and keeping everything up to date. Good luck!

Comment: hmm... you're right... back to the drawing board

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible? Yes, you can use whatever process you want. Git Flow is (1) a set of guidelines for how to use branches in Git, and (2) a set of scripts to automate the implementation of those guidelines. In this answer I'll focus on (1), but it should be simple to extend the scripts to help you implement your chosen solution.

One thing you are missing from the standard workflow:

```
dev    -> feature/*  ->  dev
dev    -> release/*  -> master (& dev)
master -> hotfix/*   -> master & dev
```

I.e., `release` branches need to be merged back to `dev` (if they have any commits).

Similar fixes would be needed for your new setup:

```
dev     -> feature/* -> dev
dev     -> stage/*   -> staging (& dev)
staging -> bug/*     -> staging (& dev)
staging -> release/* -> master (& staging) & dev
master  -> hotfix/*  -> master & staging & dev
```

As you can see, the number merges that must be done increases exponentially.

I have two alternative suggestions, one a slight spin on the standard workflow, and the other a simpler extended workflow that I'm using for a project currently.

### Standard Git Flow

Again, for reference, the standard Git Flow workflow is:

```
dev    -> feature/*  ->  dev
dev    -> release/*  -> master (& dev)
master -> hotfix/*   -> master & dev
```

Instead of using a dedicated long-lived `staging` branch to deploy to your staging environment, set up your [CI/CD](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery) system to automatically deploy to staging whatever the latest `release` branch is.

I recommend this option, since it keeps things the simplest, but it may be difficult to set up your CI system to deploy the latest `release` branch.

### FF-Only Production

Here's an overview of this setup:

```
dev     -> feature/* -> dev
dev     -> release/* -> staging (& dev)
staging -> hotfix/*  -> staging & dev
staging -> --ff-only -> master
```

This setup is useful for production deployments that need to be **very** stable. Note that *nothing* is ever merged into `master`; even `hotfix`es get merged into `staging`. When the `release` or `hotfix` has been tested on staging, do this to update production:

```
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only staging
git push origin master
```

This workflow is pretty close to the one you suggested, but still drastically cuts down on the number of merges, and also has the benefit of requiring very few changes to the standard git-flow scripts.

Comment: Yes, up until now we were never pushing a commit to a release branch and the work always originated on dev making its way to master. The release branches were more a point of reference in case of a rollback. Production tracked master.  We have decided to go with keeping production tracking master, but with a subtle difference of pushing release bug fixes to the release branch in Q and indeed merging the release branch into master and dev. So our only step now is finding a solid solution to enable this to happen. Thanks for your detailed answer.